# removing dict entries by key using startswith

Tags: python

I have a dict containing several entries beginning with '_'.
I want to get rid of all this entries using:

```
for key in item:
    if key.startswith('_')
        del item[key]
```

But i get a syntax error on  *if key.startswith('_')*

Is this method not allowed on key for dicts?

Comment: are all keys of type `string`? Even if one of them is not, it will not work.

Comment: Yes, for print (type(key)) i get <class 'str'>

Comment: you are missing the `:` on the `if`

Comment: you miss `:` at the end of `if` statement

Comment: Sh.... sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the `:` at the end of the if.

```
for key in item:
    if key.startswith('_'): # <----------
        del item[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is syntactically wrong. You need a : at the end of it like this

```
for key in item:
    if key.startswith('_'):
        del item[key]
```